# Codeigniter including javascript files

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a beginner question.

I am uesing a few plugins for my site.
I included jquery , and jquery ui in my header like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and i included the main js file what i created for global stuff on the site in the footer.

So i dont really want to include the js in the footer what takes effect only on like: the details page

os is it ok if i include jquery in the header, include the main js in the footer, and include the details js in the details view file?

thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your base_url is working.In case its not working please set the base_url in the config file and then use this.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your URL helper is loaded.

Make sure you have your base_url set in your config with trailing /.

For your JS - You could keep as is or put all in the footer.
Load Jquery first, then ui, then your own js.

For Jquery - use google cdn and your server as backup.